# Database Tutorial: The method open() is undefined for the type MainActivity.DBAdapter

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I am trying to do this database tutorial on SQLite Eclipse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-IV87qQ00M

But I get a few errors at the end..

at db.ppen(); i get error:  The method open() is undefined for the type MainActivity.DBAdapter 
and similar for insert record and close.

MainActivity:

```
    package com.example.studentdatabase;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     addassignment.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    try {           
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/AssignmentDB";
        File f = new File(destPath);            
        if (!f.exists()) {          
            CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"), 
                new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(); 


    //---add an assignment---

    db.open();        
    long id = db.insertRecord("Hello World", "2/18/2012", "DPR 224", "First Android Project");        
    id = db.insertRecord("Workbook Exercises", "3/1/2012", "MAT 100", "Do odd numbers");
    db.close();


    //---get all Records---
    /*
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllRecords();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {          
            DisplayRecord(c);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    */

    /*
    //---get a Record---
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getRecord(2);
    if (c.moveToFirst())        
        DisplayRecord(c);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Assignments found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();
    */


    //---update Record---
    /*
    db.open();
    if (db.updateRecord(1, "Hello Android", "2/19/2012", "DPR 224", "First Android Project"))
        Toast.makeText(this, "Update successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Update failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    db.close();
    */

    /*
    //---delete a Record---
    db.open();
    if (db.deleteRecord(1))
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
    db.close();
    */
}

private class DBAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    //private ArrayList<>

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        return null;
    }

}

public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) 
throws IOException {
    //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}

public void DisplayRecord(Cursor c)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, 
            "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
            "Title: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
            "Due Date:  " + c.getString(2),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
} 

public void addAssignment(View view)
{

    Intent i = new Intent("com.pinchtapzoom.addassignment");
    startActivity(i);
    Log.d("TAG", "Clicked");
}

}
```

DBAdapter code:

```
package com.example.studentdatabase;

public class DBAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_DUEDATE = "duedate";
public static final String KEY_COURSE = "course";
public static final String KEY_NOTES = "notes";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AssignmentsDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "assignments";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table if not exists assignments (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "title VARCHAR not null, duedate date, course VARCHAR, notes VARCHAR );";

private final Context context;    

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);    
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}    

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---    
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a record into the database---
public long insertRecord(String title, String duedate, String course, String notes) 
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
    initialValues.put(KEY_COURSE, course);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NOTES, notes);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//---deletes a particular record---
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

//---retrieves all the records---
public Cursor getAllRecords() 
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_DUEDATE, KEY_COURSE, KEY_NOTES}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

//---retrieves a particular record---
public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_TITLE, KEY_DUEDATE, KEY_COURSE, KEY_NOTES}, 
            KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

//---updates a record---
public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String title, String duedate, String course, String notes) 
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_DUEDATE, duedate);
    args.put(KEY_COURSE, course);
    args.put(KEY_NOTES, notes);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
}
```

addassignment code:

```
 package com.example.studentdatabase;


public class addassignment extends Activity {

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add);

}
public void addAssignment(View v)
{
    Log.d("test", "adding");
    //get data from form
    EditText nameTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
    EditText dateTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDuedate);
    EditText courseTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCourse);
    EditText notesTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNotes);

       db.open();        
       long id = db.insertRecord(nameTxt.getText().toString(), dateTxt.getText().toString(), courseTxt.getText().toString(), notesTxt.getText().toString());        
       db.close();

    nameTxt.setText("");
    dateTxt.setText("");
    courseTxt.setText("");
    notesTxt.setText("");
    Toast.makeText(addassignment.this,"Assignment Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

}

public void viewAssignments(View v)
{
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
}
```

}

What is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two classes named `DBAdapter`. The other is an inner class in the `MainActivity`, the other is a separate class. `open()` is defined in the separate class while `MainActivity` implicitly uses the inner class version.

To fix it, either use fully qualified package names to refer to the class, or just rename the other class to separate the two.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I renamed the DBAdapter class to DBAdapterX. I still have the same undefined errors.

(Sorry I don't know very much about Java programming..)

Comment: You need to update the references to that DBAdapter you need.

Comment: I believe I did that when renaming via Refractor->Rename...?

DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(); Is that part above db.open() correct? Is it meant to point to the DBAdapterX class?